# save data in array coming from 2 different uitableviews in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Recently i am facing an issue in saving data of Uitableview inside Uitableview cell in ios swift

[Senario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyCly.png)

Questions asked in above pictures is one table view  and this table view cell contain 1 label for question text and uitableview that show possible answers provided by admin  and user is allowed to select one.i am enable to display data perfectly  but facing an issue when trying to save answers of every question in one array.it always store the value  of last  questions answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using two different UITableView? Any specific reason? You can get data from different resources but there is no need to use two table views.

You should use a section header view to show the questions & sections rows as options(answer option).

You can dynamically add or delete the options(rows) from any section(question). Also, there will not be the above scenario if you implement it using this easy approach.

Let me know in case of any query.